# How to implement file downloader to detect communication breakage?

Tags: c#, .net, download

I need to implement a file downloader in C#. This downloader will be running on the client computer, and will download several files according to several conditions.

The main restriction I have is that the client will probably go offline during downloading (sometime more than once), so I need the following things to happen:

1) Downloader should notice there isn’t any network communication anymore and pause downloading.

2) Downloader should resume downloading once communication is back, and continue collecting the packages, adding them to those that were already downloaded to the local disk.

I have checked StackOverflow previous posts and saw that there are two options – WebClient and WebRequest (using one of the inheritance classes). I was wondering if someone can advise which one to use based on the requirements I have specified. How can I detect communication breakage?

Comment: Thanks. Note that thank you notes/signature/tags in title are not recommended in posts.

Answer (score 0):

You will need **System.Net.HttpWebRequest** to send HTTP requests and **System.IO.FileStream** to access files. Two methods needed are **HttpWebRequest.AddRange** and **Filestream.seek**

HttpWebRequest.AddRange method adds a byte range header to the request, and the range parameter specifies the starting point of the range. The server will start sending data from the range parameter specified to the end of the data in the HTTP entity. While Filestream.seek method is used to access the current position within a stream.

[Source and example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b1c67073-ac98-43b5-a211-aca252965467)

Comment: This maybe correct answer... but so far OP seem to want information on "How can I detect communication breakage" (assuming the rest is already known)...

Comment: Well, he has 2 questions of which I answered the 1st one "advise which one to use based on the requirements"

Answer (score 0):

You need download resume (if supported by server you are downloading from) which means you should go with `WebRequest` since with `WebClient` you cannot do that (probably next versions will support RANGE requests).

As soon as connection is dropped your code which is reading network stream throws an exception. That tells you there is a problem with download (i.e. network problem) then you can **try** in some periods to make a new connection and if succeeded, resume from last successful byte (using RANGE in HTTP HEADER).